# Prevent table corruption with historical data - MariaDb / MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb, corruption, historical-db

I am working on a MariaDb database, in which there is a table called **event** that can calmly store 6-8 million monthly records. Although the data that is stored does not have much information, since it is simple records of events that occur, composed of 3 columns.

So I would like to prevent possible corruption of the table and my initial idea is, at the end of each month, to create a new historical table with the name in the format **event_month_year**, and dump the data of the corresponding date. Example:

- **event_jan_2022**
- **event_feb_2022**
- **event_mar_2022**

In this way, if I want to access the information of the current month, I will just query to the table **event**, but if I want information of previous dates, then I will query to the table by its name in the format that I just explained (**event_month_year**).

I don't know if this way is the most correct, the most optimal or elegant or not. Surely there are other, better ways to do it, so I'd like to hear opinions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up `CREATE TABLE .... PARTITION BY ...` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-management.html

Comment: There is one simple method to prevent data loss while any damaging. It is referred to as BACKUP. *at the end of each month, to create a new historical table with the name in the format event_month_year* - this is very bad idea. I agree with @RiggsFolly - the partitioning is more useful.

Comment: I didn't know Partition Management. I will read about.
Regarding backup, I do it every 24 hours. But still, in addition to preventing table corruption, the idea was also to prevent query slowdowns. Thanks to both.